# ASP.NET Web API - difference between XML and XHTML?

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web API to return data as either XML or XHTML.  I'm using Razor views for each format, as well as custom formatters.  The XML is not whatever the Web API produces, it is custom based on a Razor view (as is the XHTML).

I would like to use the same controller action for both formats and just have content negotiation determine which is returned. Is it possible to drive the return format based on the requesting client's ACCEPT header?  Or is this not possible since both are essentially custom formats?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  CustomFormatters behave the same way as default formatters.

Comment: If a client has the same accept header when requesting either format, it seems another piece of info is needed to determine which format they want for a given request.

Comment: Why can't I delete a duplicate comment?

Comment: Normally you would use the accept header to select the format.  However, you can also use a parameter in the URI, such as format=xhtml or an extension like .xhtml.  Both are supported in Web API.

Comment: Thanks, parameter works.